# How to modify Accumulo VisibilityFilter?

Tags: accumulo

One of the responses to this older thread mentions the possibility of modifying the Accumulo VisibilityFilter:

[How to determine Accumulo table visibilities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27000271/how-to-determine-accumulo-table-visibilities)

We have a slightly different need than the question in that thread, but we were wondering how to go about doing what was suggested by Christopher in the April 22, 2015 response, i.e., how to modify the VisibilityFilter?  Does Accumulo have some kind of hook to do that, or would it involve breaking open one of the Accumulo JARs and replacing the org.apache.accumulo.core.iterators.user.VisibilityFilter class with our own custom implementation?

Thanks!

Jim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache Accumulo is [open source software](https://opensource.com/resources/what-open-source). One need not "break open" any jars in order to modify its behavior. Rather, you can simply [obtain its source code](https://accumulo.apache.org/downloads/), modify it, and build it from source.

Accumulo does not have any built-in hooks to modify the behavior of the VisibilityFilter. The response in the other question was referring specifically to the nature of open source software, and the ability to modify the code to change its behavior.

(For what it's worth, I don't think a separate StackOverflow question was necessary to clarify an answer on a different question. StackOverflow provides a comment feature, which can be used to ask clarifying questions, and the response on the original question could have been edited with a clarifying update instead.)

Comment: @Christoper - sorry about making a new question, but I was not sure whether it was "better" to start a new question or comment on the other one.  I will comment on the other one with my followup then.  Thanks.

Comment: @user555303 It's not a big deal. I just thought I'd mention the comment feature and how it might be used to get the best possible experience from StackOverflow in the future :)